# multiple submit buttons and enter key

Tags: c#, asp.net, focus, master-pages, submit-button

I have a master page with a search bar and a submit search button, and then on my other pages there may be a form with a submit button. I found a answer to this question before which was I believe to have my Search be put into a asp:Panel and set that DefaultButton to the submit search button. So my master page's .aspx code looks like this:

```
 <asp:Panel ID = "searchBoxPanel" runat = "server" DefaultButton="SearchBTN">
<asp:TextBox ID="searchText2" class="search-query row-fluid" placeholder="Search"  runat="server" onfocus="Search_Focus"></asp:TextBox>
 </asp:Panel>

 <asp:Button ID="SearchBTN" runat="server"  onclick="SearchBTN_Click" Text="Search Postings"/>
```

So the weird thing is, on my login page for example, if I am in the login form and hit enter, it knows to hit the login submit button.

However, I have some other pages where I have the same .aspx code for the submit button but when I hit enter, it thinks I am hitting the search button.

For comparison sake, here is my login .aspx code (which works correctly when I hit enter)

```
<asp:Button ID="loginBTN" runat="server" UseSubmitBehavior="true" onclick="loginBTN_Click" Text="Log In" />
```

and here is another button for another page which does not work correctly

```
<asp:Button ID="anotherBTN" runat="server" UseSubmitBehavior="true" onclick="anotherBTNClick" Text="Test" />
```

Comment: Are you sure your anotherBTN is also in panel having DefaultButton="anotherBTN" ??? So when you hit enter it will call anotherBTN code

Comment: Do I need to add a panel for all the buttons on the page as well as the search button on the master page then?

Answer (score 2):

Each Button has to be in a separate, unique Panel.

```
<asp:Panel ID="pnl1" runat = "server" DefaultButton="btn1">
  <asp:Button ID="btn1" runat="server" Text="Sea" />
</asp:Panel>

<asp:Panel ID="pnl2" runat="server" DefaultButton="btn2">
  <asp:Button ID="btn2" runat="server" Text="Log In" />
</asp:Panel>

<asp:Panel ID = "pnl3" runat = "server" DefaultButton="btn3">
  <asp:Button ID="btn3" runat="server" Text="Log In" />
</asp:Panel>
```